# Is there a way to display a pygame window over OpenGL?

Tags: python, opengl, pygame, pyopengl, opengl-compat

I've been meddling around with PyOpenGL and pygame, and I managed to create an FPS-style camera object. Now I want to add a crosshairs in the middle of the screen, and potentially expand to display statistics on the sides of the window.

I've already looked into this, and it seems like you have to do some weird stuff with OpenGL like disabling depth test and changing the projection matrix, and until now none of that actually renders anything, and reduces performance.

It seems to me that it should be very easy, as all I want is something that is over everything else, and doesn't ever move. Is there really no way to tell pygame to draw over OpenGL so I can just draw two lines in the middle of the screen?

Comment: No there is no specified way to do that. Do it in OpenGL it is not that complicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is no specified way to do that. Do it in OpenGL it is not that complicate.

According to your previous questions, I assume you want to do it in immediate mode using `glBegin` - `glEnd` sequences.
In the following I assume that `width` is the width of the window and `height` its height. You have to disable the depth test and back up the current matrices by [`glPushMatrix`/`glPopMatrix`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glPushMatrix.xml). Load the [Identity matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_matrix) for the model view matrix and setup an orthographic projection corresponding to the window size ([`glOrtho`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glOrtho.xml)):

```py
cross_size = 100

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
glPushMatrix()
glLoadIdentity()

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
glPushMatrix()
glLoadIdentity()
glOrtho(0, width, height, 0, -1, 1)

glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)

glColor3ub(128, 128, 128) # color of the crosshair
glBegin(GL_LINES)
glVertex2f(width/2 - cross_size/2, height/2)
glVertex2f(width/2 + cross_size/2, height/2)
glVertex2f(width/2, height/2 - cross_size/2)
glVertex2f(width/2, height/2 + cross_size/2)
glEnd()

glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
glPopMatrix()
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
glPopMatrix()
```

Ensure that 2 dimensional texturing is disabled (`glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)`)